# Value is null when passed as parameter

Tags: excel, powershell, com

I'm working on reading from an excel spreadsheet to mass format some text.  When I do something like the following, everything works fine.

```
Function Read-From-Excel {
    Param(
        [string]$fileName,
        [string]$sheetName="Sheet1"
    )

    $excelObject = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
    $excelObject.Visible = $FALSE
    $excelBook = $excelObject.Workbooks.Open($fileName)
    $excelSheet = $excelBook.Sheets.Item($sheetName)
    $intRowMax =  ($excelSheet.UsedRange.Rows).count

    $col = 1
    $row = 1

    $headers= @()

    While ($TRUE) {
        $column = $excelSheet.cells.Item($row, $col).Text
        If ($column -eq "") {
            Break
        }
        $headers += $column
        $col ++
    }

    $text = ""

    For ($row = 2; $row -le $intRowMax; $row++) {
        # Wrapped in another function starting here    
        $cell = $excelSheet.cells.Item($row, 1).Text

        If ($cell.StartsWith("#")) {
            $text += "-- {0}`n" -f $cell.substring(1)
        } Else {
            $c1 = $cell
            $c2 = $excelSheet.cells.Item($row, 2).Text -creplace '\s+', ''
            $c3= $excelSheet.cells.Item($row, 3).Text -creplace '\s+', ''
            $c4 = $excelSheet.cells.Item($row, 4).Text
            $c5 = $excelSheet.cells.Item($row, 5).Text

            $text += Format-Row $c1 $c2 $c3 $c4 $c5
        }
        # Until here
    }

    Write-Host $headers
    Write-Host $text
    $excelObject.quit()
}
```

When I wrap the inner section in a function, however, I get the error:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\dannnno\desktop\FormatFromExcel.ps1:311 char:27
+     $cell = $excelSheet.cells.Item <<<< ($row, 1).Text
    + CategoryInfo               : InvalidOperation: (Item:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId      : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

That function looks like this

```
Function _Get-Next-Block-Excel-File {
    Param(
        [Object[]]$sheet,
        [int]$row
    )

    # This is all the same, except with the name changed to $sheet
}
```

and the original code had the internal section changed to look like

```
$text += _Get-Next-Block-Excel-File $excelSheet $row
```

Is there a special way I have to pass this parameter in PowerShell?

Comment: How many times around the `For ($row = 2; $row -le $intRowMax; $row++) {` loop does it get before chucking that exception?

Comment: I can't repro this. I'd suggest running this in PowerShell ISE or PowerGUI and setting a breakpoint on that line to see what's going on. Also you don't need an `Object[]` array as the first parameter in `Function _Get-Next-Block-Excel-File`, `[Object]$sheet` will do fine because you're not passing an array of sheets to that function.

Comment: Also a sample of your source data which causes this to choke would be useful, I suspect it's something in there. One final note, you should also make `$text` private in your `_Get-Next-Block-Excel-File` function, otherwise it clobbers your `$text` in the calling function. See: http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tips/archive/2010/10/18/working-with-private-variables.aspx

Comment: @Kev It was actually the `[Object[]]$sheet` that was causing the error - removing that makes everything work.  If you'd like to answer to that effect I'd be happy to accept and upvote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need an `Object[]` array as the first parameter in `Function _Get-Next-Block-Excel-File`, `[Object]$sheet` will do fine because you're not passing an array of sheets to that function.